# Setting Values to Non-Existent Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Whether via JavaScript or jQuery, are there any detriments to setting values to elements that don't exist?

In some of my generic functions that addresses dynamically-built DOMS, some class elements are assigned values and attributes but they might not always exist.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean? Include any code you can.

Comment: Without a clear statement or an specific situation, this should not be a problem...

Comment: The only detriment the cycles taken up by searching for the non-existent elements. In general though, this is not a major performance concern

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements that aren't connected to the DOM and do any operations to them that you'd do to normal DOM element. This is often a better approach because all your changes to the disconnected DOM element won't cause the browser to redraw. Then, after you've applied all your changes, you can attach that element to the DOM and only cause the browser to redraw once.

Likewise, you can assign as many classes as you wish, whether there are styles associated with them or not doesn't matter.